# invincibility frame and take damage class

Tags: c++, sfml

i am a beginner and i have already read a doc but i need to practice for learn and now i am stuck.

So i would like to do a class takeDommage for apply a number of dmg and activate a countdown for create the invincibility frame.

so i tryed this (see code under)

It's the first class i create alone so i don't understand what's wrong

main :

```
if(Collision::PixelPerfectTest(sprite_perso,sprite_ennemis))
{
    std::cout<<"collision pp"<<std::endl;
    takeDommage::prendreDegat(10);
    std::cout<<pv<<std::endl;
}
```

takeDommage.h :

```
#ifndef TAKEDOMMAGE_H
#define TAKEDOMMAGE_H

    #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cmath>


class takeDommage
{
    public:
        takeDommage();
        prendreDegat(int Dommage);

        //virtual ~takeDommage();

    protected:
        sf::Clock takeDammageClock;
        int Dommage;

    private:
};

#endif // TAKEDOMMAGE_H
```

takeDommage.cpp

```
#include "takeDommage.h"

takeDommage::takeDommage()
{

}

void takeDommage::prendreDegat(int Dommage)
{
    if(takeDammageClock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds()>=3)
        {
            std::cout << "bite" << std::endl;
            pv -= Dommage;
            takeDammageClock.restart();
        }
}
```

error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in TheGameSFML (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
E:\Work\Top_secret\code\TheGame\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
E:\Work\Top_secret\code\TheGame\main.cpp|168|warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]|
E:\Work\Top_secret\code\TheGame\main.cpp|180|warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]|
E:\Work\Top_secret\code\TheGame\main.cpp|217|error: cannot call member function 'int takeDommage::prendreDegat(int)' without object|
E:\Work\Top_secret\code\TheGame\main.cpp|156|warning: unused variable 'enemySpawnTimer' [-Wunused-variable]|
E:\Work\Top_secret\code\TheGame\src\takeDommage.cpp|8|error: prototype for 'void takeDommage::prendreDegat(int)' does not match any in class 'takeDommage'|
include\takeDommage.h|15|error: candidate is: int takeDommage::prendreDegat(int)|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 3 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: `takeDommage::prendreDegat` is an _instance method_. As the error message says, you need an _object_ to call it, i.e. `takeDommage td = ...; td.prendreDegat(10);` You're currently trying to call it as if it were `static`.

Comment: ok, i was trying but idk how to do that ^^"

Comment: where is the if statement placed in?

Comment: the "if(collision ..." is in main in the game loop and the "if(takeDommage..." is in the takeDommage.cpp

Answer (score 1):

you seem to be very new in c++. the compiler already telling you what's wrong with it.
`error: cannot call member function 'int takeDommage::prendreDegat(int)' without object|`

you need to instantiate (create) your object first. the way you accessing as if the takeDommage function is a static function which is not. its public a member function of takeDamage

assuming that you have instantiated your takeDommage class somewhere before the if statement call,

```
TakeDommage Obj;
...
...
if(Collision::PixelPerfectTest(sprite_perso,sprite_ennemis))
{
    std::cout<<"collision pp"<<std::endl;
    Obj.prendreDegat(10); //calling the prendredegat member function of Obj
    std::cout<<pv<<std::endl;
}
```

in addition to that you are missing the return type `void` before the function name of `prendreDegat`

```
class takeDommage
{
    public:
        takeDommage();
        //prendreDegat(int Dommage); //missing void
        void prendreDegat(int Dommage); //correct way. which can be translated as Prendredegat returns nothing.
```

Comment: now i have "error: 'pv' was not declared in this scope" but i have declared pv in main

Comment: I can't tell why without seeing everything. I'm pretty sure pv, is not within the reachable scope area of where the if statement is placed. is the if statement within the main? best to edit your question and add the missing bits of the codes

Comment: @Jules variables are bound by the scope in which they are defined. A variable in `main` is only visible in `main`.  A variable defined in a `for` loop in `main` is only visible in that `for` loop. I recommend against editing the question to add another question. This question is to-the-point, specific, and well answered. Tacking on more questions broadens the question and it becomes less useful to askers that follow. When one answer results in answers that spawn new questions, ask new questions.

Comment: @Jules, as user4581301 mentioned best to ask another question if this doesn't help. from the edit, i can tell you that the reason you had the issue with your global `pv` variable not getting accessed is that it's out of scope. `pv -= Dommage; is causing the problem`. a quick fix would be passing the pv as another argument to prendreDegat.  make sure to change your current prendreDegat declaration too if you do this. like; `void takeDommage::prendreDegat(int Dommage,int pv)`